# Are there types of standard coaxial cable with a propagation velocity of 0.9c? What would be the application?

Tags: electromagnetic, coax, propagation

Reading [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/358900/83380) I was surprised to hear that there are "excellent" kinds of coaxial cable with a propagation speed of 0.9c; 90% the speed of light.

The bargain basement number is about 2/3c, and coaxial cable with a faster propagation velocity would have to have a lower dielectric constant. Assuming \$v/c\$ scales as \$1/\sqrt{\mu_r \epsilon_r}\$ as it would in free space, that would mean the cable would have a relative dielectric constant of 1.2 for example.

Does this exist as a standard product? If so, are there applications where having "excellent cable" with such a high propagation velocity would be important? Or would it be a side-effect of other desirable properties of the dielectric?

Comment: Signals in a hurry? I have read of using line-of-sight tower to tower laser links from NY to Chicago to shave a few ms off the fiber transit time to give a competitive edge to stock exchange trading companies. (I've also read of a company adding a 32 km coil of fibre in their switchroom to add a few ns delay to users to limit the rate of transactions.) These thinks matter to some folks.

Comment: The "best" I have seen is around 0.8x and I have never seen a case where it is necessary to have a special factor, just some where you need to know it.

Comment: @Transistor more like a ms than a ns. So this cable was invented for high speed stock trading?

Comment: I haven't a clue. I don't think coax is used for long distances anymore. Fiber took over a long time ago.

Comment: @PlasmaHH right. It's often important to know it, and in some situations that it be very stable, but I can't think of any reason why it would need to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Links like the ones mentioned by @Transistor also exist between London, Berlin and Paris, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: 99% of times when you see cable performance measured in fraction of lightspeed, it's just a marketing gimmick in order to sell veblen goods. Fasten your wallet and look up "audiophile cable".

Comment: The high velocity specs translates into lower loss, more air than plastic and more copper $$ more rigid and more bandwidth were all standard rigid coaxial trunks for 300+MHz  CATV in the 1980’s before fibre was more cost-effective. Reducing C from lower mu was the goal while maintaining impedance error tolerances from O/I diameter ratio damage

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Air lines still exist, with velocity factor very close to 1.0. These are AFAIK mainly used in old-fashioned VSWR measurements. The advantages are that the dielectric constant of air is fairly stable and well-known, and that you can insert a probe (a tiny antenna) into the middle of the transmission line without damaging the dielectric.

ePTFE (aka "Teflon foam") dielectric typically gives a velocity factor of about 0.85. These cables are, in my experience, used because they maintain low loss to fairly high frequencies and their phase delay is quite stable under variations of temperature and flexure, not specifically because of the high phase velocity. I've used them in test and measurement applications, and I imagine they're also used in things like radar and avionics.

I found a reference saying that "foam polystyrene" dielectric gives a velocity factor of 0.91, but I have no experience with such cables, and I don't know what applications they're favored in. In fact I couldn't (with 2 minutes googling) find any vendor actually selling them.

Comment: This is a great explanation of the situation, thank you!

Comment: LMR 1700 http://www.timesmicrowave.com/documents/resources/LMR-1700.pdf has a velocity factor of 0.89. The insulation material is gas-injected polyethylene.

Comment: @davidmneedham, thanks. One of my references also said ePTFE can reach 0.9 (presumably when made with higher air content). But I find 0.85 is much more common.

Answer (score 7):

The high propagation velocity would be a "side effect" of more desirable property -  signal loss/dissipation along a cable. Losses are dependent on properties of isolation material. If you already have the best low-loss material, the next thing is to make it porous, so it will mostly contain dry air. The higher propagation velocity is a side effect of this.

Comment: Makes sense; the only thing better than having the best *is having less of it* :-)

Comment: Just as an extra comment, if you end up working with higher frequencies such as 10 or 20 GHz, the loss per foot for regular coax starts to be very large.

Answer (score 4):

Some (older?) coaxes suspend the center conductor with glass beads every so often. Thus most of the dielectric is air. Propagation velocity is almost 1.0 \$c\$.

Comment: That's really interesting! I'd love to read about that or see a picture if possible. As long as the bead-lumping distance was way smaller than the wavelength, I suppose it's no different than the air pockets in foam or the dielectric spacing in ladder lines.

Comment: Show me a coaxial cable with a velocity factor of 1.0. Even "air core" coax has a sub 1.0 vf.

Comment: @W5VO even a beam of light six feet wide traveling in a vacuum will travel slightly slower than the speed of light. See [Wouldn't any structured beam of light be expected to travel slower than a plane wave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/269052/83380). Somehow I missed that last sentence-fragment in the answer, thanks for pointing it out. Indeed Nothing really travels at exactly 1.0 c other than "infinite plane waves".

Comment: @uhoh Some applications use _rigid line coax_, which is essentially a copper tube suspended in a copper tube ([example image](https://www.eriinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/macx650.jpg)). [EEVblog #569 - Tour of an Analog TV Transmission Facility](https://youtu.be/mR_wJkxKSXU?t=2884) is a fascinating video about high-power analog RF devices, including rigid coax.

Comment: @marcelm thanks for the links! I will watch the video tomorrow, I got distracted by [all of the cool coax](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/331156/102305) your linked image led me to!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the link to the image from the eriinc.com site in @marcelm's [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/330936/#comment777381_331025) (from which another page links to commscope.com) I've been enjoying some amazing pics of coax instead of doing work.

Here's the [rigid line coax](https://www.eriinc.com/product/macxline-macx675b-series-6-18-inch-75-ohm-rigid-coaxial-line-with-bellows/) and dielectric space from the comment and [a similar one](https://www.eriinc.com/product/macxline-macx450-series-4-116-inch-50-ohm-rigid-coaxial-line-with-bellows/):

[image: rigid line coax 1]  [image: rigid line coax 2]

but they also have [a link](https://www.eriinc.com/catalog/transmission-line/coaxial-cable/) for coaxial cable at [Commscope](http://www.commscope.com/Product-Catalog/Wireless/Product/Transmission-Line-Systems/Transmission-Lines/#collapseRelResources) where there are some very nice low volume dielectric spacers; [HJ11-50](http://www.commscope.com/catalog/wireless/product_details.aspx?id=1452), [H5-50](http://www.commscope.com/catalog/cables/product_details.aspx?id=45150) and [HJ9HP-50](http://www.commscope.com/catalog/wireless/product_details.aspx?id=1466) with propagation speeds of 92%, 92% **and 96% the speed of light!**

[image: HJ11-50]

[image: H5-50]

[image: HJ9HP-50]

Comment: Those spiral spacers are where the "heliax" name comes from. Although nowadays it also encompasses foamed PE dielectric which is more conventional, but still manages 88-91% Vf by being mostly air.

Answer (score 1):

The high velocity specs translates into lower loss, more air-core than plastic and more copper $$ more rigid and more bandwidth were all standard rigid coaxial trunks for 300+MHz  CATV in the 1980’s before fibre was more cost-effective.

Reducing C from lower mu was the goal while maintaining impedance error tolerances from O/I diameter ratio damage.

This also raises impedance from higher L/C suitable for some apps unless the centre diameter is increased to compensate with lower L thus more $$ to get back to 75 ohms for CATV or 50 ohms for almost everything else.